# Place footnotes at the bottom of a page, where notes are in the text

Tags: javascript, css, xml

I'm preparing a few manuscripts for online publication. I would like to have a workflow where I can author in something like Word and convert to XML to have it handy for different platforms.

The thing I'm struggling with is how to format the footnotes for one platform.

I cannot save the doc as .html and use that code, because the platform already uses "class=note" for something specific.

I've converted an .rtf to xml to get something like this:

```
<body>
Lorem ipsum<note n="1" place="foot" xml:id="ftn1">Footnote text here</note>. The main text continues on.
</body>
```

I'm hoping that I can have footnotes (endnotes, really) appear after the body, with the footnote number @n appearing after the text. Ideally, I can have these hyperlinked.

Comment: Can you not just set `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` on the desired element?

Comment: Unfortunately, the footnotes kind of stack up at the bottom of the page--beneath the comment section and metadata/versioning info. I also need the footnote number (@n) to appear next to the text.